# Abbreviated numerical values

Tags: numbers

I'm presenting a quick power point showing a venue's revenue stream. I don't want to give specific numbers, so I'm generalizing with numerical abbreviations. Revenue is over a million, but the remaining costs and balances are in the hundreds(or tens) of thousands.  Is it acceptable to convert $1,059,000 million in revenue to $1,060K so that it looks more cohesive with 450K, 600K, and so on?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from doing so.

Comment: This is a writing advice request.

Answer (score 2):

You want all your units to match up ideally:

(preferred)

- $1,059K
- $450K
- $600K

or

- $1.059M
- $0.45M
- $0.6M